# How to derive: $\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n < 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$

Tags: calculus

In my textbook they write the following inequality: $\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n < 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}+...+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$

They say that they derive this inequality by viewing the expression $\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ As a geometric series. But I am not sure how they come to that conclusions. Any tips?

Comment: For what $n$ is this supposed to hold?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can arrive at this by using the binomial theorem and the inequality $k!\ge2^{k-1}$ for $k\ge1$, viz:

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{n^k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{n^k}\le\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}$$

$$=1+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k!}\le1+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$$

Comment: I think this is what they meant. Anything that starts out 1, 2 and grows more slowly than k! will do. $2^{k-1}$ fits nicely and is easily summable.

Answer (score 3):

The RHS equals $1+\sum\limits_{i=0}^k \frac{1}{2}^k=1+\frac{1-\frac{1}{2}^{k+1}}{\frac{1}{2}}=3-\frac{1}{2^k}$ which monotonously ingcreasing converges to 3. 
The LHS converges monotonously increasing to $e$. In particular it is smaller than e. So there just remain 3 values of n to be tested, because then the RHS is bigger than e.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!